# Display html img located in network drive

Tags: wamp, unc, nas

I am running WAMP on a server with an online website. My camera generate pictures each 5 minutes in a folder: C:/wamp/www/website/data/camimg but it takes lot of space in the local drive (C:) so I need to put theses pictures in my network NAS (Z:) that is attached to the machine.

How can I do to specify to WAMP that pictures in camimg folder are in X:/camimg ?

I tried to put UNC path  but that doesn't work.
I tried alias directory too but same result.